# Data passing error from javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC project , I want to get location dropdown  selected value and according to that i need to  load values to City  dropdown  , i implemented following code and location dropdown onselect event call the javascript function  and javascript function call the controller method  but when executing controller  method locationId is  null ,and i debug javascript and locationID is there till the this  line  `data: JSON.stringify({ locationId: +locationId })`, after that javascript  returns error.but  controller method get hit but locationId null

code for dropddowns

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Localizer["Locations"]
        <select id="locationDropDown"  class="selectpicker form-control" asp-for="selectedLocation" onchange="getCityList()">
            <option value="0">&lt;None&gt;</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.LocationList)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Localizer["KioskGroup"]
        <select id="cityDropDown" class="selectpicker form-control">
            <option>---Select City---</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
function getCityList()
        {
        debugger;
            var locationId = $("#locationDropDown").val();
            console.log(locationId)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Kiosk/GetZoneListBYlocationID',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'application/json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ locationId: +locationId }),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#cityDropDown").html("");
                $("#cityDropDown").append
                ($('<option></option>').val(null).html("---Select City---"));
                $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, zone) 
                { $("#cityDropDown").append($('<option></option>').val(zone.Id).html(zone.Name)) })

            },
            error: function(){alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")},
        });
```

controller method

```
  public ActionResult GetZoneListBYlocationID(string locationID)
        {
            List<Zone> lstZone = new List<Zone>();
            long locationId = long.Parse(locationID);

            var zones = _zoneRepository.GetZonesByLocationId(locationId);

            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zones));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is sending the json string `{"locationId":101}` in the **request body** because you specified the contentType as `application/json`. This is useful when you want to send an object with multiple properties and your action method parameter is a DTO/POCO class type. Model binder will be reading from the request body and map it to the parameter.

In your case, all you are sending is a single value. So do not send the JSON string. simply create a js object and use that as the `data` attribute value. Also remove the `contentType: application/json` as we are not sending a complex js object as json string.

Also `application/json` is not a valid option for the `dataType` property. You may use `json`. But jQuery is smart enough to guess the value needed here from the response headers coming back from server. So you may remove it.

```
function getCityList() {

    var locationId = $("#locationDropDown").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Kiosk/GetZoneListBYlocationID',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { locationID: locationId },
        success: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
           // populate dropdown
        },
        error: function () { alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..") },
    });

}
```

Now this data will be send in Form Data as `locationID=101` with Content-Type header value as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and will be properly mapped to your action method parameter.

You should use the correct types. In your action method, you are using `string` as your parameter and later trying to convert it to `long`. Why not use `long` as the parameter type ?  Also if `zones` variable is a list of `Zone` object, you can pass that directly to the `Json` method. No need to create a `string` version in between.

```
 public ActionResult GetZoneListBYlocationID(long locationId)
 {
    var zones = _zoneRepository.GetZonesByLocationId(locationId);
    return Json(zones);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Why you are `stringify`  the data.Below one should work without `stringify`

```
data: { locationId: +locationId },
```

Comment: Please check xhr tab in console network tab and see the payload

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. and after that, I have tried below solution. 
Hope it will help you.

ajax call is as follows:

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Account/GetCities",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#StateID").val() },
                success: function (states) {
                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                       $("#CityID").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve cities.' + ex);
                }
            });
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
public List<CityModel> GetCities(int id)
{
        //your code
}
```

You can do in your application like this:

```
function getCityList()
        {

            var locationId = $("#locationDropDown").val();
            console.log(locationId)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Kiosk/GetZoneListBYlocationID',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { locationId: locationId },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#cityDropDown").html("");
                $("#cityDropDown").append
                ($('<option></option>').val(null).html("---Select City---"));
                $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, zone) 
                { $("#cityDropDown").append($('<option></option>').val(zone.Id).html(zone.Name)) })

            },
            error: function(){alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")},
        });
}
```

And your controller will be same as you have done.